# "Shapeless" objects in c#

Tags: c#, object

I am receiving objects using wcf, each object is different and I would like to instead of creating an object for each received object so I can manipulate it, to pass/copy each received object to only one shapeless object each time. It there such a thing?

A pseudo-code example:

```
Shapeless_object = received_obj_A;
if (Shapeless_object.name = "I_dont_know") {
   Shapeless_object.count++;
}

Shapeless_object = received_obj_B;
if (Shapeless_object.name = "I_dont_know_too") {
   Shapeless_object.count--;
   Shapeless_object.age = 20;
}
```

received_obj_A and B are different with different parameters
but passed in a single object. I hope I made my question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You mention WCF origins: it is easy to add interfaces to WCF types via `partial class`: just declare the common interface - perhaps:

```
interface ICommon {
    string name {get;}
    // ...
}
```

Then tell the compiler to infer the interface for each of your WCF types:

```
namespace TheWcfNamespace {
    partial class SomeWcfType : ICommon {}
    partial class AnotherWcfType : ICommon {}
    partial class WhateverWcfType : ICommon {}
}
```

As long as `SomeWcfType` etc all *have* the members to implement the interface, you can now treat all your WCF objects as `ICommon`.

---

Alternatively, you might be able to do what you want here via `dynamic` - just replace `Shapeless_object` with `dynamic` - however, that seems an abuse of the intent. A more classic implementation here would be interfaces:

```
if(obj is IDontKnow) {
   // TODO: access as an IDontKnow
}

if (obj is IDontKnowToo) {
    // TODO: access as an IDontKnowToo
}
```

You can of course combine this with the `partial class` approach mentioned above.

Comment: @user on the contrary: at the server there's **no need** for the `partial`, since you control the originating type; it is *specifically useful* for generated types - I hate to say it, but `partial class` was pretty much **created** to help you make tweaks to generated (WSDL etc) types (without having to edit the generated content)

Comment: Wow, thanks! Your answer is way over my head! Although it seems the right one. The dynamic option seems to be working for me!

Answer (score 1):

You could cast them to `dynamic`, but it would be a performance hit.

```
dynamic shapeless = received_obj_A;
if (shapeless .name = "I_dont_know") {
   shapeless.count++;
}

shapeless  = received_obj_B;
if (shapeless.name = "I_dont_know_too") {
   shapeless.count--;
   shapeless.age = 20;
}
```

Note that you do lose static typing, obviously.

Comment: Hey thank you! It works but I need to cast to `dynamic` in every receiving a have. So it's `dynamic shapeless = received_obj_A;` and `dynamic shapeless  = received_obj_B;`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var a = received_obj_A;
if (a.name = "I_dont_know") {
   Shapeless_object.count++;
}

var b = received_obj_B;
if (b.name = "I_dont_know_too") {
   Shapeless_object.count--;
   Shapeless_object.age = 20;
}
```

Dont use the base object here, because you need to check for the instance and try to cast it.

**Don't do:**

```
object a = received_obj_A; // Here you need to cast

if (a.name = "I_dont_know") {
   Shapeless_object.count++;
}

object b = received_obj_B; // Here you need to cast
if (b.name = "I_dont_know_too") {
   Shapeless_object.count--;
   Shapeless_object.age = 20;
}
```

Comment: @anon if there was an option for `var a = received_obj_A;` and `var a = received_obj_B;` this would be the answer.