# Access many objects with same method within a foreach statement

Tags: c#, object

I have many objects of different type all with the same method `.getStatus`. I would like to access all the objects' method inside a foreach statement. Example:

```
String[] names = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
foreach (string name in names) {
   dynamic obj = name.getStatus(); //instead of a.getStatus();
   //Do
   //some
   //stuff
   //here
}
```

Unfortunately the name parameter which is a string does not have a `.getStatus` option. Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: do not use `dynamic`for this. Use Inheritance!

Comment: I took the idea from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406856/shapeless-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: you want to call a method by it's name or you want to get an object by it's name and then call the .getStatus() method from it ?

Comment: I want to do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If all your different objects have the same method `getStatus` then you should have an Interface `IHasGetStatus` which contains this method.

All your objects should be declared with and implement this interface.

With this setup, inside your loop, you may cast each object to the `IHasGetStatus` and acces the method `getStatus` of this interface.
(With the `as` operator you have smoother error handling)

```
foreach(object o in myObjects)
{
    IHasGetStatus ihgs = o as IHasGetStatus;
    if(ihgs == null) // error: o has not the required interface
    var status = ihgs.getStatus();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option since the objects are received through wcf.

Comment: So please add all constraints to yor question. What Do You know About These Objects?

Comment: I know their type and that they have a getStatus method. It would be ideal if i could use the `dynamic obj = name.getStatus();` but instead of interpreting the previous as `dynamic obj = "a".getStatus();` to interpret it to `dynamic obj = a.getStatus();` using the `name` in the foreach statement.

Comment: @George you are getting object instance with method implementations from wcf?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the objects are fed over WCF so I assume you have the proxy classes for the WCF service generated.

By default, all proxy classes for WCF services are generated as `partial` and as such you can indeed implement an interface to those classes once they are generated by implementing the interface in another file. You'll have to implement it for each type with an arbitrary method that will then call the type's `GetStatus()`, but in your `foreach` loop you'll be able to use the solution by @DrKoch.

(just in case you're not familiar with partial classes [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx])

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, you can achieve same results in a similar way by using extension methods, which allows you to "add" a method to a non-static sealed class. Again, you'll have to do this for each type individually, and again it assumes that you know the types in advance and have access to them, e.g. through a referenced assembly or WCF proxy class.

(just in case you're not familiar with extension methods [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx])

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to achieve this (in the case you can't /don't want to use interface)

assuming you have an object Collection 'myObjects' and not only the names

```
 foreach(object Obj in myObjects)
    {
    //depending on the visibility of your method you may need Bindings flags
    MethodInfo dynMethod = Obj.GetType().GetMethod("getStatus");
    var status = (string)dynMethod.Invoke(Obj, null);
    //with parameters => dynMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { methodParams });
    }
```

in the case you just have class/Type names you should probably use something like this (not tested but should works) :

```
String[] names = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
foreach (string name in names) {

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("...Assembly.dll");
    Type type = assembly.GetType(name);//name should be the full type name (Namespace.ClassName)
    //here you get your Object instance
    object Obj= Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
    MethodInfo dynMethod= Obj.GetType().GetMethod("getStatus");
    var status = (string)dynMethod.Invoke(Obj, null);
}
```

Comment: It's object is of different type although they contain the same method with different data. It is possible?

Comment: yes it is because each time your get the real type of your object with`.getType()`  in order to  find your _GetStatus_ method and then call it from your Obj which is your real instance. so every time it will call the good _GetStatus_

Comment: and classInstance to...., i updated my answer according to this.
But if you have an Object collection instead of just names , the first option is easier to use.

Comment: I don't know how to implement the object collection.

Comment: what kind of result do you get from WCF ? 
strings or differents type Instance ?

Comment: I am receiving objects with several parameters, mostly strings. Also, using your second example i get an error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74333/discussion-between-george-and-emmanuel-m).